# Wordpress - screen scaling in full

Tags: css, wordpress, slider

I am building a website for me. I have a MetaSlider plug installed. I would like photography to scale on the screen in its entirety (without having to scroll through the screen). Ideally, the "first screen" should also display the menu bar (bottom). How to do this?

```
<?php 
    echo do_shortcode("[metaslider id=62 percentwidth=100]"); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give your menu a height of 50px (or whatever you like) and then add this height to your slider images:

```
.sticky_header {height: 50px}

.metaslider .slides img {
  height: calc(100vh - 50px); /* The height of the viewport - the height of your menu */
}
```

Ideally, you should add to the slider images: `object-fit: cover;`, so this way it won't distort the image.

```
.metaslider .slides img {
   height: calc(100vh - 50px); 
   object-fit: cover;
}
```